# PHP while loop add by 2

Tags: php, loops, scripting

Currently I have a code that looks like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=($num_newlines - 1); $i++) 
{
$tweetcpitems->post('statuses/update', 
                    array('status' => wordFilter("The item $parts[$i]  has been released on Club Penguin. View it here:   http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/swfviewer/items.swf?id=$parts[$id]")));
sleep(90);
}
```

What I want to do make the "i++" part add by two and not one, but how do I do this? Please help!

Comment: You may want to spend a little time getting a basic understanding about how flow statements like `for` work (and PHP code in general).  This is a pretty trivial question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this question was pretty basic, but I wanted to make sure that I got it correct because I didn't want to end up with an infinite loop. Something like it happened to me before, and I don't want to risk another chance. I always have to ask the pros at SOF. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=($num_newlines - 1); $i+=2) {
```

Comment: curious, why wouldnt you do `for ($i=0; $i<$num_newlines ; $i+=2)`

Answer (score 6):

```
$i++ : increment by one

$i+=2 : increment by two

$i+=3 : increment by three
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to increment pair of numbers (like 1-2 to 3-4):

Solution one:

```
//initial values
$n_left = 1;
$n_right = 2;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    
    print "\n" . $n_left . "-" . $n_right;   
    
    $n_left =+ $n_left+2;
    $n_right =+ $n_right+2; 
}
//result: 1-2 3-4 5-6 7-8 9-10
```

Solution two:

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= 9; $y+=2) {
    
    print "\n" . ($y+1) . "-" . ($y+2);  

}
//result: 1-2 3-4 5-6 7-8 9-10
```